# Using conditionals in Scheme

Tags: scheme

I have to create the following:
A Scheme procedure named 'proc2' which takes 4 numbers as arguments 
and returns the value of the largest argument minus the smallest.

So I want to write
(define proc2
      lambda(a b c d)
      ...
)

Is there any way I can evaluate (> a b), (> a c), (> a d) at the same time? I want to get the largest (and the smallest)number without having to write nested ifs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use the `max` and `min` procedures? if the answer is yes, it's pretty simple:

```
(- (max a b c d) (min a b c d))
```

If not, remember that `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=` accept a variable number of arguments, so this is valid code and will tell you if `a` is smaller than `b` and `b` is smaller than `c` and `c` is smaller than `d` (although you'll have to test more combinations of `b`, `c`, `d` to make sure that `a` is the smallest value).

```
(< a b c d)
```

Also remember to consider the cases when two or more numbers are equal (that's why it's a good idea to use `<=` instead of `<`).

Anyway, you'll have to use conditionals. Maybe nested `if`s, or perhaps a `cond` to make things simpler - you can work out the details yourself, I'm guessing this is homework.

Comment: "... tell you if a is the smallest number..." No, it won't. +1 for the min/max, -1 for the second part. Hu.

Comment: A mess of (< a b c d) permutations in conditionals is not the right answer.  Recursion is the boring answer, while **map** does what the OP asked for in the way the OP asked if it could be done.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the smallest and largest members of the list and you are not allowed to use the standard **min** and **max** library functions, then I can think of three approaches

1. Write your own min and max functions (hint: recursion).  Apply both to the list to find your two values.  Perform the subtraction.
2. Write a combined function (again, recursive) which will pass through the list once, returning another two-member list which contains the max and min.  If the first element in the returned list is the max, then `(apply - (find-min-and-max 3 2 8 7))`, where **find-min-and-max** is your function, would return the result of the subtraction.
3. Use **map**.

Option 1 is less efficient than option 2 but much simpler to write.  Option 3 is more complex than either but actually does what you asked (that is, compare **a** to **b**, **c** and **d** "at the same time").

For example, if I defined the following function:

```
(define (compare test x l)
  (map (lambda (y) (test x y)) l))
```

then

```
(compare < 3 '(1 2 4))
```

would return `(#f #f #t)`

How is this useful to you?  Well, if `(compare < x l)` returns all true, then **x** is smaller than all elements of **l**.  If it returns all false, then **x** is bigger than all elements of **l**.  So you could use **map** to build the code you want, but I think it would be ugly and not the most efficient way to do it.  It does do what you specifically asked for, though (multiple simultaneous comparisons of list elements).